# Structuring two conditional left outer joins into one query using LINQ, C#

Tags: c#, linq

Currently, I am executing two queries based upon whether  `w.Type` is either 1 or 2. If `w.Type` is 1 we perform a join to the Issues table and if the Type is 2 we join to the TSubs table. I am trying to merge these queries into one.

```
var productIdOne = (from w in listAbandonedCarts
                    join i in Issues on w.ProductId equals i.Id
                    where w.Type == 1
                    select new { i.Title.Name }).ToList();

var productIdTwo = (from w in listAbandonedCarts
                    join ts in TSubs on w.ProductId equals ts.Id
                    where w.Type == 2
                    select new { ts.Title.Name }).ToList();
```

I am considering using two left outer joins based upon this SQL psuedo-code

```
SELECT*
FROM P_carts pc
LEFT OUTER tSubs ts on ts.id = pc.productid and pc.Type = 2
LEFT OUTER issues i on i.id = pc.productid and pc.Type = 1
```

So far i have some linq pseudo coded but i'm struggling to get the syntax correct for the two conditional joins

```
 var listProducts = (from w in listAbandonedCarts
                     join i in Issues on w.ProductId equals i.Id into iN && w.ProductId == 1
                     from i in iN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join  into ts in TSubs.....
```

The problem I'm struggling with is that this isn't a double left outer its two separate joins. My current error is that i cannot have `w.ProductId` after the equals because I'm out of scope of w at this point and can't figure out how to structure the linq statement. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
        var productIds = (
            from w in listAbandonedCarts
            from i in Issues.Where(issue => issue.Id == w.ProductId && w.Type == 1).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from t in TSubs.Where(tsub => tsub.Id == w.ProductId && w.Type == 2).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new {Name = (w.Type == 1 ? i.Title.Name : t.Title.Name)})
            .ToList();
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, thank you very much. I have up-voted but as i'm new it wont show up here.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var listProducts = (from w in listAbandonedCarts
                 join i in Issues on w.ProductId equals i.Id && w.ProductId == 1 into iN 
                 from i in iN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 join  into ts in TSubs on ts.id equals  pc.productid into tsBag
                from ts in tsBag.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                  // All columns you need 
                };
```

Please try the above linq. This sample code is not compiled nor tested. Please use this for reference purpose only.